# Can't connect to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to install Apache because I want to do PHP development work.

The install didn't work so I aborted it and wanted to make sure that my other installs using MySQL were still working.

I can no longer seem to connect to my SQL server though.

HeidiSQL returns:

```
SQL Error (2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)
```

Ruby on rails on Server start up returns:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

MySQL Command Line Client returns:

```
Error 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

I've tried the suggestions found in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385292/mysql-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10061

and have come with the following results:

```
telnet localhost 3306
Connecting to localhost... Could not open connection to host, on port 3306: Connect failed
```

sc query mysql
[SC] EnumQueryServiceStatus:OpenService Failed 1060:
The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

Yet when I look in SQL Server Configuration manager, it says SQL Server (SQLExpress) is in a running State.

I can't seem to troubleshoot this issue. Please help!

Comment: SQL Server = Microsoft SQL Server which is completely different product to MySQL (well .. they both DBs, but they are _different_ products).

Comment: @Zigu if you would kindly respond to this and help us clarify what is going on in your environment. Otherwise, I think this question is a lost cause because ... it sounds like you are in way over your head and if you've abandoned this question then it's too localized.

Comment: Apologies for the non response. I was able to resolve the issue with Randy Melder's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are running MySQL on Windows, although you did not mention it. If so, look in your Services and makes sure the MySQL service is started. Here is a [link explaining what to do at dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html).

If you are trying to connect to SQLExpress, the process is the same as above to make sure the service is running. Then, here is a link explaining [PHP SQLExpress connectivity using PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php#86668).

Comment: Hm. manually starting the MySQL service resolved the issue. My set up used to have MySQL firing as part of start up but I guess something must have taken it out of the initial boot. Now I have to do this every time I wanna use MySQL :S

Comment: @Zigu: You can set the service to start automatically, not manually.

Answer (score 1):

`SQL server configuration manager` shows you the settings for Microsoft SQL server. You may have an instance of SQL express running on your machine. To administer MySQL, you can use the command line: `Mysql -u user_name -password`, if MySQL is in the path, or you can use [MySQL workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) if you don't already have it. It looks like MySQL may be down, and you will have to restart it.